# Raster algebra to tiled maps on a sever with open source solutions

Tags: raster

Let's say I have a collection of data in raster format.  It changes daily.  Once each day I would like to do some fairly complex raster algebra on these datasets.  I would like to be able to do the calculations automatically (so I don't have to manually run the calculations).  Ideal I can use python to code the calculations.  I would like to take the results of the raster calculations and then tile them up to be used as a service displayed on my website.  Again, I'd like to do this automatically, so that I don't have to set up the tiles each day.  I am pretty sure I can do this with some collection ESRI products, but it would be great to have an open solution.  I suppose that once I have the results of the raster algebra, I could use geoserver or similar to distribute the results, but a more streamlined solution would also be good.

Bottom Line: What software can I use to do raster algebra calculations on a sever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use postgresql/postgis for tiled raster storage. You can do a fair amount of band math directly with raster functions, esp. if you want to constrain these to feature delineated subsets (e.g. a polygon for a particular land class). You can parse postgis raster selections into python (using gdal) and integrate with opencv if you need to do more complex image processing. Whatever you generate, you can push back into postgis. Geoserver links directly into postgis.

All easily packaged in hands-free scheduled scripts, running on linux ("what else?"). You can't get it much opener than this...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out GeoTrellis? http://geotrellis.io Doing Map Algebra on the server is what it's designed for. We've implemented local, focal, zonal summary, global operations, vector -> raster, raster -> vector. For large data, it can parallize on one machine with Akka and we're working towards full Spark support for cluster computing. It's a Scala library, Apache 2.0 licensed.

Full disclosure: I'm the lead of that team.

Answer (score 0):

to perform raster algebra in an automated way, I would either use gdal or OTB. With gdal, you have gdal_calc.py and with OTB you have the application called otbcli_BandMath. Both are command line application that you can launch in a batch script.